# How to change a kernel module's compilation option from yes to module without causing boot failure?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

**My Purpose**

I want to edit and debug the kernel module `FUSE`. I think compiling the `FUSE` kernel module to be loadable and removable (can be `insmod`ed and `rmmod`ed, instead of setting the option `yes`, which compiles the `FUSE` module into a part of kernel) would be a good idea, cause after I edited its source code, I just need to run `rmmod fuse;make;insmod fuse.ko` instead of compiling the kernel again and reboot, which costs a lot of time.

**What problem I encountered**

But after I execute `make menuconfig`, I see the default option of `CONFIG_FUSE_FS` is set `y`.(btw with the default configuration file the system can boot successfully).

After I manually set it to `m` and finish compilation and installation, the system hangs as the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49V9X.png). If I choose other kernel installed originally to boot, the system can boot successfully. btw I'm using ubuntu20.04 virtual machine.

**What I have tried**

I have tried to follow the hint in the picture, which is adding the argument `rootdelay=100` but it does not help.

So how can I change the option from `y` to `m` without causing boot failure? Or is there another way that I can edit and debug the kernel conveniently?

Comment: "If I choose other kernel installed originally to boot, the system can boot successfully." - So, have you tried to set option `CONFIG_FUSE_FS` to `y` and to boot the compiled kernel? It seems like `CONFIG_FUSE_FS` option is absolutely not related to your problem in loading the kernel...

Comment: What is the kernel command line? Or more to the point, what is the root filesystem?

Comment: depending on your distro and boot options, you may need to rebuild your initrd.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm sorry I checked up the conf again and I find that the system can boot successfully with `CONFIG_FUSE_FS` being setting `m`. I guess the reason I ran into the problem is that I execute `sudo make install` before `sudo make modules_install`. after I thange the order it can boot successfully. I guess the reason I would mistakenly think it's changing of `CONFIG_FUSE_FS`'s value matters is that after I recompile the kernel again I execute `sudo make install` again. I do it in wrong order is because I tested it successfully in centos but not in ubuntu yet...